# Google Analytics download tracking in SharePoint 2007 publishing sites

Tags: 2007, publishing

Has anyone got this to work without adding the specific java script to each and every link?
I’ve tried both of these solutions

http://www.goodwebpractices.com/roi/track-downloads-in-google-analytics-automatically.html

http://www.iqcontent.com/blog/2006/11/tracking-document-downloads-in-google-analytics/

Without success, maybe I’m doing something wrong.

**Update 1**

I have added the GA tracking code to the master page and statistics are being recorded, however the downloads are not.

Comment: Can anybody suggest 3rd party tools, if available, to track downloads, clicks, video watch, flash interactions, search tags etc., for selected web pages of a sharepoint 2007 implemented publishing Internet site, instead of inserting some script!

Comment: Help me out to solve the codes above. I tried copying website like SoundCloud but some of my programmes are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jQuery this this is the code I eventually figured out...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var ext = new Array(); 
    ext = ['pdf', 'zip', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'mp3', 'txt', 'vsd', 'rar', 'wma', 'avi', 'mmv']; 

    for (var i in ext)
    {
        var fileType = 'a[href$="'+ext[i]+'"]';

        $(fileType).live('click', function() {

            var link= $(this).attr("href");        
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', link]);
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download', 'Click', $(this).text()]);
        });        
    }
});
```

there is one draw back to this - any content loaded via ajax e.g. a grouped by column webpart will not fire the click event, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010475/delegate-not-binding-to-anchor-elements-tag)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the google analytics page tracking to the master page. I got it working read this article which helped me.

http://mikeknowles.com/blog/2009/07/11/EnableGoogleAnalyticsPageTrackingInASingleNameIntranetSite.aspx

Comment: Master page is definitely the way to go.

Comment: forgot to mention that I do have the tracking code already added the master page and it is reporting statistics, just not the downloads

Comment: So have you added onclick code to the anchor link on the page? This doesn't happen automatically - you have to enter it manually or write javascript to parse the doc on page load and do it. Do you have a page to share?

Comment: I see now thats what the taglinks.js that you linked to should be doing - break out IE dev toolbar and see if its working. Have a page to share and we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry forgot to say SetDomainName to none

So it should look something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'Your google tag here']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']); 
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If I understand how Google Analytics works, I don't believe you can use it track downloads. The script loads when a page is loaded to track the user. When you click to download a document, you aren't loading another page... you're just downloading the document.</strike>

As @Ryan points out, you could track document downloads on a page using GA's "[virtual page views](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55529)". You would probably need some additional JavaScript on the page that attaches the code to the onclick event of every link pointing to a document. A downside, is that this will not track document downloads that the user was directly linked to (ex: emailed doc link to a user).

If you need to track *all* downloads, you'll need to consume the IIS logs which tracks every request.

Comment: Yes you can - you can track additional actions (such as clicks on links that go to a download using) using 'virtual page views' e.g. _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','someurl') or you can track as events - see http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiEventTracking.html

Comment: @Ryan: Interesting... so you'd need additional JS on your page that parses out any link to a document to add the tracking code. Also, what about if a user receives a direct link to a document?

Comment: Yes - you either put that code in a onclick manually or write some javascript to parse the page onload and input. If direct link to document then nothing runs 'client side' so GA won't work - then you're looking at some server side log parsing solution.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that is good info. I've updated my answer to include it.